# How to load PluggableDevice into tensorflow to use Mac M1 GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, rust, tensorflow2.0, apple-m1

I have successfully built tensorflow v2.9 C library by following this [gist](https://gist.github.com/lnshi/eb3dea05d99daba5c932bbc786cc3701) on Mac M1.

When I check the devices in Rust code, only CPU device is available. `bundle.session.device_list()` only returns CPU device:

```rust
let bundle = SavedModelBundle::load(
    &SessionOptions::new(),
    &["serve"],
    &mut graph,
    export_dir
).expect("Unable to load model from disk");

println!("{:?}", bundle.session.device_list() )
```

```
Device { name: "/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", device_type: "CPU", memory_bytes: 268435456, incarnation: 10072007419359857694 }]
```

The Rust code are using bindings to tensorflow's C API (e.g. `device_list` = `TF_DeviceList`). Apple M1's GPU is supported by MPS plugin (https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/). From my test, it does work in python. The MPS is implemented as a [PluggableDevice](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2021/06/pluggabledevice-device-plugins-for-TensorFlow.html) to tensorflow, that is to say, it can be loaded without modification to tensorflow source code.

How can I use the deivce plugin in tensorflow?

Comment: Think you might have better luck on https://superuser.com/

Comment: @JeshuaLacock I dont think it is a question to building process.  It is more about coding. Here I updated the question with more information.

Comment: It is a much better question now; but it still seems related to package installation so I suspect people are more likely to help on SU. Just offering a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @JeshuaLacock, it is a coding question,  answered below

Comment: Well except your answer specifically mentions plug in installation and environment variables. You probably wouldn't have had to answer your own question on SU. Anyway; glad you got it figured out.

Comment: The key is the API call.  The environment variables are not nessesary.  Installation is not a problem because the files were already there. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

There is an experimental API called [`TF_LoadPluggableDeviceLibrary`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api_experimental.h#L324)

So first ensure Apple's metal plugin is installed, then find the location of file `libmetal_plugin.dylib`. Either copy this file into `PATH`, or add its directory into `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

On application startup, before loading the model, load this library first:

```rust
pub fn load_plugable_device(library_filename: &str) -> Result<(), Status> {
    use std::ffi::{ CString };
    let c_filename = CString::new(library_filename)?;
    
    let raw_lib = unsafe {
        let raw_status: *mut tf::TF_Status = tf::TF_NewStatus();
        let raw_lib = tf::TF_LoadPluggableDeviceLibrary(c_filename.as_ptr(), raw_status);
        if !raw_status.is_null() {
            tf::TF_DeleteStatus(raw_status)
        }
        raw_lib
    };

    if raw_lib.is_null() {
        Err(Status::new())
    } else {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

I am using Rust bindings and this experimental API is missing in `tensorflow-sys` crate. Hence I add it there. You may check my github [repository](https://github.com/wangjia184/rust) for source code.

Then the lovely GPU is enabled.

```
2022-08-17 08:16:29.397578: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:43] Reading SavedModel
2022-08-17 08:16:29.401477: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:81] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2022-08-17 08:16:29.401500: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:122] Reading SavedModel debug info (if present) 
Metal device set to: Apple M1

systemMemory: 16.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 5.33 GB

2022-08-17 08:16:29.411250: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:306] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2022-08-17 08:16:29.411398: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:272] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)
2022-08-17 08:16:29.422914: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:354] MLIR V1 optimization pass is not enabled
2022-08-17 08:16:29.427004: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:227] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2022-08-17 08:16:29.429435: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
2022-08-17 08:16:29.440099: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:113] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
```